# Adding a document and adding a sub-collection to that document Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
db.collection("rooms").add({
        code: this.state.code,
        words: []
      }).then(() => {
        db.collection("rooms").where("code", "==", this.state.code).get().then((doc) => {
          doc.collection("players").add({name: this.state.name, votes: 0}).then(() => {
            socket.emit("createGroup", this.state.code);
          });
        });
    });
```

I am building a React/Express app using client-side Firestore calls and SocketIO. I'm getting the following error in console: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.collection is not a function". I guess the Firestore document -> `{code: this.state.code, words: []}` has somehow not yet been created when I reference it in the then function -> `db.collection("rooms").where("code", "==", this.state.code)`. Any suggestions on how I can fix this error while still maintaining the order of the Firestore calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `get()` on a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query) object as you are here:

```
db.collection("rooms").where("code", "==", this.state.code).get()
```

It's going to return a promise that yields a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) object.  That object does not have a method called `collection()` on it.  It contains the results of the query that you will have to deal with.

You're going to have to iterate or otherwise handle the results of that query to move forward.  Your code should also be prepared for the case that that query returns no documents. Use the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) array property on the QuerySnapshot to learn about what happened.

```
db.collection("rooms").where("code", "==", this.state.code).get().then(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach(snapshot => {
    // handle each document individually, if any
  })
});
```

I suggest also reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) on Firestore queries, along with the API documentation I linked above.

Comment: Okay cool that makes sense, thanks for your answer! So if I take a query snapshot of that document like you suggested, I can then call the collection method on the document from the snapshot?

Comment: Yes, you can get a document reference out of document snapshot and build a path from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection("rooms").add({
        code: this.state.code,
        words: []
      }).then(() => {
        db.collection("rooms").where("code", "==", this.state.code).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.ref.collection("players").add({name: this.state.name, votes: 0}).then(() => {
            socket.emit("createGroup", this.state.code);
          });
        });
    });
  });
```

This implementation works thanks to help from Doug.